# Como fazer request em um site usando token de sessão

Tags: python, python-3.x, session, python-requests, token

No caso eu tento entrar no link firefaucet.win/start com o seguinte código:

```
import requests    
requests.get('https://firefaucet.win/start')
```

Esse request retorna à página de login do site, e não para o local do link. Como o login é feito com captcha (e o objetivo final do código é automatizar um request), eu acredito que seja mais fácil usando o token da minha sessão, que eu já tenho (era um cookie). Mas como eu faço isso? Como eu faço o request entrando na conta usando apenas o token?

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Se tal interação for permitida pela empresa desse site, estará explicado em algum manual/documentação de sua API.

Comment: explicitamente não tem nenhuma permissão ou não de fazer isso, porque o token de sessão faz parte do login comum, utilizar ele diretamente pulando a parte de login seria só um método mais rapido de entrar na conta.

Answer (score 1):

```
# Valor 'f919208d949256bc062e5c23e02ba9a2' é um exemplo
# Obtenha o valor real no cookie de uma sessão autenticada
# Verifique nas ferramentas de desenvolvedor do seu navegador    
cookie_dict = {"session": "f919208d949256bc062e5c23e02ba9a2"} 
requests.get('https://firefaucet.win/start', cookies=cookie_dict)
```

Answer (score -1):

Eu li bastante na [documentação da lib requests](https://docs.python-requests.org/pt_BR/latest/) e a resposta é só fazer um objeto de sessão (`request.Session()`) e em seguida fazer o request usando o cookies kwarg, que é padrão como `None`. Só lendo que o token de sessão é guardado no cookie chamado "session" no navegador, eu atingi o objetivo apenas pondo o token de sessão dentro do cookie "session" assim como no código abaixo:

```
import requests
obj = requests.Session() # cria o objeto de sessão

response = obj.request( # variavel recebe a resposta do request feito no objeto de sessão

    'get', # metodo de request
    'https://firefaucet.win/start', #link a ser utilizado
    cookies={ # dicionario com 'nome do cookie': 'valor do cookie'
        'session': 'token de sessao aqui'
    }
)
print(response) # imprime a resposta que o request gera, se der tudo certo retorna o código 200
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).